# Playing audio repeatedly in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to play one music repeatedly until user presses the toggle button off..

I am not able to figure out how to do that,
Please help

Comment: please give more information and your code also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use

```
MediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

for repeating sound using MediaPlayer.You can find more info about it in [setLooping](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Comment: that's called solution, thank you for inform one more property !